# Python bindings for libparted?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to interact with the GNU `libparted` library from Python, but so far what I've found, a [GSOC](http://code.google.com/soc) [project from 2005](http://pylibparted.tigris.org) and an [Ubuntu/debian package](https://edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-parted) that's been [dropped from the archive](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=379034), have been disheartening.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I just get used to manipulating `libparted` from the command line / trying to fix the bitrot that's occurred in the other packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like the [pyparted](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pyparted) library?

Comment: Ah, yes. That's what I was looking for, I just couldn't find it among the other unmaintained and abandoned projects.

Answer (score 2):

The reason debian dropped the package is lack of a maintainer. If you are willing (and able) to maintain the existing package and become their maintainer that would be a great contribution to FOSS.

Comment: Yeah, I already maintain two packages in debian but I'm not much of a C programmer; upstream has gone out of business and I don't have the technical skill to adopt it. (it doesn't even compile OOTB on Ubuntu Jaunty)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro) to generate a Python binding for it. It works for QT so it may work for libparted.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but you can also checkout [reparted](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/reparted/), it's a ctypes python binding.